# How to logically combine integer indices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone know how to combine integer indices in numpy? Specifically, I've got the results of a few `np.where`s and I would like to extract the elements that are common between them.

For context, I am trying to populate a large 3d array with the number of elements that are between boundary values of each cell, i.e. I have records of individual events including their time, latitude and longitude. I want to grid this into a 3D frequency matrix, where the dimensions are time, lat and lon.

I could loop round the array elements doing an `np.where(timeCondition & latCondition & lonCondition)`, population with the length of the where result, but I figured this would be very inefficient as you would have to repeat a lot of the `where`s.

What would be better is to just have a list of wheres for each of the cells in each dimension, and then loop through the logically combining them?

Comment: `np.where(timeCondition & latCondition & lonCondition)` should actually be a lot quicker than calling `np.where` separately for each condition - that way you are only looping over each element once

Comment: So, as far as the efficiency goes - the problem was that individual conditions in the np.where's where being repeated. So for example, when looping over longitude points, I would have np.where(timeCondition & latCondition & lonCondition1) followed by np.where(timeCondition & latCondition & lonCondition2) i.e. have to search for timeCondition & latCondition more than once for no reason. I figured that if I just did them all once and stuck them in lists which I could then loop over comparing the elements, it must be quicker. Does that sound right or not?

Comment: Depending on what the condition is used for, it can pay off to multiply with the mask instead of index with it. I've used that to optimize some loops in a matrix factorization algorithm, to good effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @ali_m said, use bitwise and should be much faster, but to answer your question:

- call `ravel_multi_index()` to convert the multi-dim index into 1-dim index.
- call `intersect1d()` to get the index that in both condition.
- call `unravel_index()` to convert the 1-dim index back to multi-dim index.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30)

idx1 = np.where(a>0.2)
idx2 = np.where(a<0.4)

ridx1 = np.ravel_multi_index(idx1, a.shape)
ridx2 = np.ravel_multi_index(idx2, a.shape)
ridx = np.intersect1d(ridx1, ridx2)
idx = np.unravel_index(ridx, a.shape)

np.allclose(a[idx], a[(a>0.2) & (a<0.4)])
```

or you can use `ridx` directly:

```
a.ravel()[ridx]
```

Comment: You certainly answered my question, however it turns out I solved the problem in a different way. I found the most efficient solution to effectively be to skip the np.where aspect. i.e. I made a list of boolean arrays for each dimension and then combined them logically with ampersands.

Comment: This is an excellent answer that also generalises to other situations, thank you. E.g. if I want to combine the results of multiple calls to `np.where` instead of getting the intersection: `ridx = np.append(ridx, np.ravel_multi_idx(where_result, source_shape))` (side note: I could use np.union1d but in my code I know the where results will not overlap so `np.append` expresses my intent more clearly)